# Version Control strategy

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

While working on a project, I want to use version control with TFS 2010.

How can I do it?

such as Project_v0.1, Project_v0.2 ....

Answer (score 1):

First add the solution to source control:

File > Source Control > Add Solution to Source Control

When you want to work on a new version of the solution, open Team Explorer, navigate to the path where you checked in the solution, right click and select branch

Once you have completed the branching steps, you can continue to work on the branch for your new version.

If you want to merge back changes from your branch to your main "Trunk" the place where you right clicked and selected branch, you can select the branch and right click and select Merge

Look at this link:
http://branchingguidance.codeplex.com/

Comment: Thank you, I supposed another solution, this is very easy :)

Comment: If you consider the question as answered, please "Accept" the answer so that the question no longer appears as an unanswered question!